# Rheostat with parallel resistor, how to make the taper more linear?

Tags: resistors, parallel, potentiometer, rheostat

I'm using a 10k potentiometer wired as a rheostat in parallel with a 470 ohm resistor, because I need a (roughly) 500 ohm variable resistance in a circuit. The type of potentiometer I'm using is not easily available in lower values.

This of course makes the pot taper highly logarithmic, or I guess reverse logarithmic, as it's called [here](http://www.geofex.com/article_folders/potsecrets/potscret.htm), meaning 90% of the maximum resistance is reached at only a small fraction of a full turn.

Is there any technique to make the taper more linear, assuming that I can only use this type of pot, but any kind of combination of resistors around it?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question you are asking, but if you want 500 ohm then you should use a bigger resistor than 470ohm in parallel with your 10k pot (e.g. 560ohm).  In that case, the range from 460ohm to 530ohm corresponds to about 3/4 of a full turn (assuming it is a 1-turn pot) and the adjustment isn't too far from linear over that range.  If it is important to prevent an accidentally low parallel resistance, then you should also put another resistor in series with the pot (e.g. 2k), though this might worsen linearity a bit (haven't done actual calculations).

Comment: Thanks! What I need in this case is a variable resistance from 0 to about 500 ohms, doesn't matter if it's actually 400 or 600, hence the 470 resistor which I had around. The linearity in the lower end of the range is most important, and this is what I'm struggling with.